# Eclipse can't find Oracle VM Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oracle, adb

I have read pretty much every post on this subject and nothing seems to work. Eclipse can not find any devices, real or emulated, to run or debug my applications. I usually use an Oracle VM and a couple of weeks ago it stopped showing up on target devices. I have reset the ADB in Eclipse but this did not work. I am sorry about the repost but I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this batch file to get ADB to work:
@

```
rem  kill/start server
Set ADBPath=D:\AndroidDevelopment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\

@REM D:\AndroidDevelopment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools\emulator-x86.exe -avd Simple_AVD

%ADBPath%adb devices

%AdBPath%adb.exe kill-server
%AdBPath%adb start-server

MORE
```

Have you set the Port Forwarding Rules for the VM Networking?   It needs to be set for ports 5037 and 5555[image]